# Android Resize Bitmap According to screen Resolution

Tags: android

I am working on a locker app where I need to show the background as the phone wallpaper, for this I am using the below xml and Java code, by this I am able to manage the resolution on some phones but on lower resolution phones Image getting stretched so please check my code that how can I achieve for all resolutions phones:

My xml Image view is:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@id/lock_iv_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

I have also used  android:scaleType="centerInside" but the same stretching problem with this too.

Java Code:

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
    Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
    // convert drawable to bitmap
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) wallpaperDrawable).getBitmap();
    getResizedBitmap(bitmap);

public void getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm) {

    DisplayMetrics metrics = getApplicationContext().getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics();
    // getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    // int width = bm.getWidth();
    // int h = bm.getHeight();

    float scaleWidth = metrics.scaledDensity;
    float scaleHeight = metrics.scaledDensity;

    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0,
            TimerPrefrences.getScreenSize("width", LockService.this),
            TimerPrefrences.getScreenSize("height", LockService.this),
            matrix, true);
    mViewBackground.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to resize your image at all. Just set:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

instead of

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your ImageView to tell it to fit it's bounds

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```